# Fingerprint implementation in iOS

Tags: ios, touch-id

> Apple has released Finger Print scanning in iOS 7.

which SDK do we use for implementation?

Answer (score 1):

There is no publicly available `SDK` for it yet. Nor there is privately available `SDK` for this.

It is only used in `iPhone 5S` but not in `iOS 7` in general.

You can't use it even if you jailbreak your device - Xcode does not publicly provide such mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

Fingerprint can be used only for unlocking iPhone and AppStore purchases. There is no public API for 3rd party developers.

Answer (score 1):

No, iOS SDK does not have any public API for TouchID access. This is done for security reasons I suppose. Confirmation from [Apple's official developer forums](https://devforums.apple.com/message/884859#884859) (You have to login using your AppleID).

There is also a *rdar://14958904* filed for this: [Touch ID API](http://openradar.appspot.com/14958904). Hopefully in future releases Apple makes the sensor data available through a public API for 3rd party developers.